# Mac to iPhone App Communication over WiFi

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, applescript

I am new to developing for the iPhone and would love some advice on an app i'm trying to develop.

Is it possible to send commands to an app on iOS 3.2 from OS X using AppleScript. The iOS app will display an image and run a small script when it recieves the appropriate command from the client software running on a Mac Mini. The devices would communicate over an a closed WiFi network.

Before I continue down this path does anyone have any advice on how to setup the communication (i.e. get the app to run in the background and listen on a designated port).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the full process but I know that various apps do this one way or another, such as 1password and desktop remote mouse apps.  I think that [CocoaAsyncSocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) will help.  An alternative to having the iOS app listening on a socket is to open a connection from iOS to OS X and then persist it.  You can then send data either way through the connection.